# Help with an SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a working generated SQL query, however I can't work out how I can count it!
The `GROUP BY` function stops a normal `COUNT(*)` from working.. hope someone can help.

```
SELECT wposts.* FROM wp_posts wposts, wp_postmeta wpostmeta 
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'phone' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '1542' 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'tips' || wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'phone' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '1541' 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'tips' || ........ 
GROUP BY wposts.post_content 
ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` and change the `SELECT` to only `COUNT(DISTINCT wposts.post_content)` to get the number of rows this query would have returned.

Comment: Thank you! I spent ages trying to work this out... should have asked earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wposts.post_content)
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'phone' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '1542' 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'tips' || wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'phone' 
AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '1541' 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'tips' || ........ 
ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
```